# Java/Groovy Gradle Build Error

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to build basic Java/Groovy project using Gradle. i have one groovy class, one jar file and and xml file with the following file structure:

Project Structure:

```
QB/
    /src/
        /main/
             /groovy/somefile.groovy
    /lib/
        /jcifs-1.3.17.jar
    /config/
        /config.xml
/build.gradle
```

The build.gradle file content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

targetCompatibility = "1.6"
sourceCompatibility = "1.6"

version = "1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.5'
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
[ant:groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[ant:groovyc] ..../QB/src/main/groovy/QuickBookSync.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class jcifs.smb.SmbFile
[ant:groovyc]  @ line 2, column 1.
[ant:groovyc]    import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
[ant:groovyc]    ^
[ant:groovyc] 
[ant:groovyc] ..../QB/src/main/groovy/QuickBookSync.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream
[ant:groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.
[ant:groovyc]    import jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream
[ant:groovyc]    ^
[ant:groovyc] 
[ant:groovyc] ..../QB/src/main/groovy/QuickBookSync.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
[ant:groovyc]  @ line 1, column 1.
[ant:groovyc]    import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
[ant:groovyc]    ^
[ant:groovyc] 
[ant:groovyc] 3 errors
[ant:groovyc] 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
Cause: Forked groovyc returned error code: 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: if you open the project in your favourite IDE and add the jcifs-1.3.17.jar manually to the class path, do this imports work or do you get an error that the required classes cannot be found (as with the groovy build)?

Answer (score 0):

`jcifs-1.3.17.jar` seems to be a compile dependency, but you made it a runtime dependency.

Comment: actually i changed it to "compile" but still no joy

Comment: Check what's on the compile class path: `task debug << { configurations.compile.each { println it }}` Does including the Jar file directly solve the problem? `dependencies { compile files("lib/jcifs-1.3.17.jar") }`